# Cartesian product of finite sets can't be countably infinite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

The problem is:

Show, assuming AC, that any Cartesian product of ﬁnite sets is either ﬁnite 
or uncountable (can’t be countably inﬁnite).

My thought is:
Finite product of finite sets is finite. This can be readily proved. Countably infinite product of finite sets is uncountable. This can be seen from the infinite sequence of 0 and 1. Uncountable product or with more than two elements is also uncountable. Trivially any Cartesian product of a set with only one element is finite. Then I'm done.

But I didn't use the ac. There should be a formal proof with ac. How to use ac? Please give me a hint.

Comment: You need AC for the mere existence of a cartesian product of an infinite number of sets.

Comment: @lisyarus : that's not true. But you need it to prove the "infinite product" bit (to choose an injection $\{0,1\}\to F$ for each of your finite sets that aren't singletons)

Comment: Amazing how you can use AC without realizing you're using it. ;)

Comment: @Dustan: You don't actually need AC here, to be honest.

Comment: @Max Isn't AC equivalent to the fact that an infinite product is nonempty?

Comment: @lisyarus : nonempty yes, but it can exist and be empty (proof : $\emptyset$ exists ! ;) )

Comment: @Max Well, that's what I was talking about, yes.

Comment: @lisyarus : sure but a product that happens to be empty is certainly finite, so that's not how AC is used

Comment: @Max Oh, got it now. Thank you!

Comment: @AsafKaragila What happens if $\{S_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb N}$ is a countable family of nonempty finite sets with empty Cartesian product, and we consider the new family $\{S_\alpha \cup \{p\}\}_{\alpha \in \mathbb N}$ with $p \notin S_\alpha \forall \alpha \in \mathbb N$?

Comment: @Dustan: You can now fix one choice function, and the define an injection from an infinite subset of the union of the family into the product. It will not be countable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm confused. Are you using AC?

Comment: It looks like the alleged "duplicate" question is about the special case $S_\alpha = \{0, 1\}$. You can't reduce the general case to the special case without using AC?

Comment: @Dustan: No. Fix a choice function $f$, and for each $a\in\bigcup A_n$ let $f_a$ be the one where you replaced the $n$th choice by $a$, where $a\in A_n$ (assume disjointness, for good measure). This gives you an injection from the union, minus the range of the choice function. If the image of this is countable that means the union of the sets is countable, so we can choose $2$ points from each set uniformly, and thus the product is uncountable. If it is not countable, well, then the product is not countable either.

Comment: @Dustan: First of all, the OP here *assumes* AC holds. So even if you can't reduce it, so what? But as I wrote, AC is kind of secondary here, since if it is countable you can use the enumeration to define a choice of pairs.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was responding to your comment "You don't actually need AC here, to be honest." I understand your reduction now - it's subtle.